# Does php add apostrophes to the default arguments of functions? If yes, how can i keep it from doing that?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Here is my function. a simple function that has a default argument passed in to the query. but the problem is when the table name is in apostrophes than the sql sees that as a string and not a table.

```
function toggleStatus($id, $table=content){
    try{
        $stmt = $this->db->prepare('UPDATE :table SET status = status+1 WHERE id=:id');
        $stmt->execute( array( "table"=> $table, "id"=> $id ) ); 
    }catch(PDOException $e){
        $debug .= "<br> ERROR:".$e->getMessage();
    }   
}
```

As a result of this query i get this error:

> ERROR:SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have
>   an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''content' SET
>   status = status+1 WHERE id='82'' at line 1

PS: when i remove the argument and write it manually then it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default you cannot parameterized column names, table names, or anything that is not a value. Parameters are design to clean up values in the sql statement.

When you pass tablename as the parameter, it is surrounded with single quotes,

```
UPDATE 'content' ....
```

causing to trigger syntax error. Try having a function which check for valid table names and concatenate it with your update statement. Eg,

```
$tableName = yourFunction('content');
$stmt = $this->db->prepare("UPDATE $tableName SET status = status+1 WHERE id=:id");
```

User define class that allows you to passed identifiers, [**safemysql**](https://github.com/colshrapnel/safemysql)

Comment: Of course it goes without saying that `$tableName` **cannot** come from the user in this case :-)

Comment: @user113215 it can. but it needs to have own logic to check for the validity of the table name. an example, though.

Comment: it is the function or is it the statement (prepare-execute) that adds single quotes to the query?

Comment: the prepare statement.

Comment: i checked and added it externally as you said and its done. thank you for the help.